# my program does't read my second line in the txt file

Tags: java

I need to prompt the user for a txt file name and then read what is inside the file. my program seems to work ok the only thing is that it only read the first line of my txt .....

these are my 2 lines

> 38 4 19 -27 -15 -3 4 19 38
>
> 14 7 -10 9 -18 -10 17 42 98

Do I have to add another scanner to read the second line? can someone please help me !

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NegativeSum{
    public static void main (String [] args )
    throws FileNotFoundException{

Scanner console = new Scanner ( System.in);
System.out.println("enter  a name of a file " );
String name = console.nextLine();
Scanner input = new Scanner ( new File (name));



        negativesum(input);


        }//end of amin

public static boolean negativesum(Scanner input)
throws FileNotFoundException{

    int sum=0;
    int count = 0;

    while ( input.hasNextInt()){
        int next =input.nextInt();
        sum+=next;
        count++;

        if ( sum<0){
            System.out.println("sum of " + sum + " after " + count + "steps" );
            return true;
            }

        }///end of while
    System.out.println("no negative sum ");
    return false;




    }//end of metho d

}//end of main
```

Comment: As you suggest, you're only calling scanner.nextLine() once. That will read only the first line. You need some sort of looping construct to read the other lines (many options available).

Comment: @user1676075: the code is *never* calling `Scanner.nextLine()`. The `nextLine` call has nothing to do with the `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need second `Scanner`. I suggest you read the file
line by line, and parse each line e.g. by using `String.split`.

Comment: Why do you think that reading a file line by line and using `String.split` (and `parseInt` afterwards) is any improvement over using a `Scanner`? And how does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The current code read the second line of the file.

The line  `System.out.println("sum of " + sum + " after " + count + "steps" );` is going to print in case the sum is less than **0** currently the sum of number is not less than 0 just add one number such that sum will be less than 0 and expected output will be printed

Comment: Its working propely on my system.Did u print the number as  System.out.println("sum of "+next); after  int next =input.nextInt(); @Yoana

Answer (score 0):

Set your program up like this

```
while(input.hasNext()) {
    if(input.hasNextInt())
        // Do your thing
    else
        input.next(); // Discard non-integer tokens
}
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm

Comment: `Scanner` ignores line breaks by default. So a line break is not a token hence there’s no need to discard it.

Comment: Removed the false claim. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a simple print statement right after

```
  int next = input.nextInt();
```

like:

```
  System.out.println(next+"\t"+sum);
```

When I tested your code it printed:

```
38  0
4   38
19  42
-27 61
-15 34
-3  19
4   16
19  20
38  39
14  77
7   91
-10 98
9   88
-18 97
-10 79
17  69
42  86
98  128
no negative sum
```

So I don’t see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I taken your code and it works as it is. you get a sum of 226 after 18 steps with the given input.
just place the System.out.println statement outside of if condition and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean negativesum(Scanner input)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += input.nextInt();
            ++count;
        } else
            input.next();
    } // /end of while

    System.out.println("Numbers parsed: " + count + "\nTotal Sum: " + sum);
    return sum < 0;

} // end of method
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is not recognising the line-breaks as anything special; which means that your input is treated as if it were one long line.  In that sense, it "works", but your question implies that that is not what you want.

I guess you want each line to be treated separately, and for the program to "reset" at the end of each line.

One way you could achieve that would be to use one scanner to read the file line by line, and then for each line, use a second scanner to read the contents of that line.  So it might look something like this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanne(new File (name));
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    negativesum(new Scanner(line));
}
```

Then you can keep your `negativesum` method exactly as it currently is.

Comment: No problem.  Happy to be able to help.

Answer (score -3):

The **return true;** cause your "if" loop to return when the first value is less that zero, so it reads only the first line.